# Two columns are dependent on the values of a third column. How to I do link these values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe as follows:

```
hello=pd.DataFrame(data={'citing':[11,13,11,15,17,18,18,17,20,15],'cited'[13,15,18,20,18,15,15,20,13,11],\
                       'firm':'A','D','A','C','D','C','C','D','F','C']})
```

The column citing has its corresponding firm value in the same row. All the elements in column-cited can be found in column-citing but in a different order. I'm trying to make another column that would list the firm values for "cited" based on the firm values that were obtained from citing.

For eg. the new column would have the values of ['B','C','E','F','E','C','C','F','B','A']. This is because 13 in 'citing' has a firm value of 'B'. Hence, 13 in 'cited' should also have 'B' in the new column. I Hope, I was able to explain this properly. Would highly appreciate if you could please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why / how is this an `r` question?

Comment: `hello$new_column = with(hello, firm[match(cited, citing)])` is your R answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map.

```
hello['firm2'] = hello.cited.map(hello.drop_duplicates('citing').set_index('citing').firm)

    citing  cited   firm    firm2
0   11      13      A       B
1   13      15      B       C
2   11      18      A       E
3   15      20      C       F
4   17      18      D       E
5   18      15      E       C
6   18      15      E       C
7   17      20      D       F
8   20      13      F       B
9   15      11      C       A
```

Comment: Thank you very much.What if my values in 'firm' were not unique and repeating? hello=pd.DataFrame(data={'citing':[11,13,11,15,17,18,18,17,20,15],'cited'[13,15,18,20,18,15,15,20,13,11],\
                       'firm':['A','D','A','C','D','C','C','D','F','C']})